# SQL commands for two tables, which need primary and foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have table structures as follows:

**Table Person :**

```
+-------+--------+
|  sno  |  sname |
+-------+--------+
|  1    | Bhanu  |
|  2    | Raghu  |
|  3    | Bunny  |
|  4    | Shyam  |
+-------+--------+
```

**Table Friend :**

```
+------+---------+
| sno  |  Friend |
+------+---------+
| 1    | 2       |
| 2    | 1       |
| 3    | 4       |
| 4    | 3       |
+------+---------+
```

- Bhanu is friend of Raghu, vice versa.
- Bunny is friend of Shyam, vice versa.

If I give the 'Bhanu' name from person table, I should be able to get his friend name as well. Which is mentioned in Friend table with respect to his `sno` values from person table.

Please do help me in performing this read operation with this kind of database.

Comment: Do you mean SQL Queries ?

Comment: yes @Kedarnath , I'm Doing Web Application with Ajax and Java Tech, SQL Commands is needed, If got the key, I can Move Ahead. Please do fine me solution. Thanks.

Comment: Good, but why you tagged this question with JAVA & Android ? you should tag it with sql,mysql tag

Comment: Okay. Sorry for that.Looking for solution.

Comment: Thats ok, there are other users who can correct your question/answer for needed. Now wait someone will answer this soon.

Comment: And what output format you want by this query ? You should describe it in your question.

Comment: Done. Please do check Question now @Kedarnath.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to access the person table twice, and so will need aliases. I suggest this table structure first:

```
person (id, name)

friend (from_person_id, to_person_id)
```

This is much the same as your table structure, but the names are a bit clearer.

Now you could have something like:

```
SELECT
    p2.name
FROM
    friend
INNER JOIN person p1 ON (p1.id = friend.from_person_id)
INNER JOIN person p2 ON (p2.id = friend.to_person_id)
WHERE
    p1.name = 'Bhanu'
;
```

That lists all the friendships going from "from" to "to". You might additionally want to list all the friendships going the other way, in which case you could add `OR p2.name = 'Bhanu'`.